# The Multi indexing here is not clear where it starts, or maybe i do not understand it well

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to understand the slicing in multiIndexing, for example:

```
health_data

subject Bob Guido Sue
type HR Temp HR Temp HR Temp
year visit
2013 1 31.0 38.7 32.0 36.7 35.0 37.2
2 44.0 37.7 50.0 35.0 29.0 36.7
2014 1 30.0 37.4 39.0 37.8 61.0 36.9
2 47.0 37.8 48.0 37.3 51.0 36.5
```

And by doing the following command:

```
health_data.iloc[:2, :2]
```

I get back:

```
subject Bob
type HR Temp
year visit
2013 1 31.0 38.7
2 44.0 37.7
```

Can anybody please tell me why the result is like this? From where do we start the index in multi indexed matrix?

Comment: Your data is not reproducible

Comment: [pandas dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) are generally lists that store different types of objects such as integers, floats, strings, etc... these have different ways of accessing the values, for example to index it we can use the  [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) method with the brackets `[]` and return the values up to the second column and up to the second row `health_data.iloc[:2, :2]`

Answer (score 2):

If I interpret your data correctly, we can rebuild your `df` as follows, using [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) and the regular `df` constructor [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), to gain some clarity about its structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tuples_columns = [('Bob', 'HR'), ('Bob', 'Temp'), ('Guido', 'HR'), 
                  ('Guido', 'Temp'), ('Sue', 'HR'), ('Sue', 'Temp')]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_columns, names=['subject', 'type'])

tuples_index = [(2013, 1), (2013, 2), (2014, 1), (2014, 2)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_index, names=['year', 'visit'])

data = np.array([[31. , 38.7, 32. , 36.7, 35. , 37.2],
                 [44. , 37.7, 50. , 35. , 29. , 36.7],
                 [30. , 37.4, 39. , 37.8, 61. , 36.9],
                 [47. , 37.8, 48. , 37.3, 51. , 36.5]])

health_data = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns, index=index)

print(health_data)

subject      Bob       Guido         Sue      
type          HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp
year visit                                    
2013 1      31.0  38.7  32.0  36.7  35.0  37.2
     2      44.0  37.7  50.0  35.0  29.0  36.7
2014 1      30.0  37.4  39.0  37.8  61.0  36.9
     2      47.0  37.8  48.0  37.3  51.0  36.5
```

- As you can see from this snippet, both your `columns` and `index` are `MultiIndices` with *names* for each level (2 levels for both: `0` and `1`), which we find in the top left corner of the print. N.B. The names are not *part of the columns/index* in the sense that you cannot use them directly to select from the `df`. E.g. your `columns` start with `(Bob, HR)`, not with `subject` and/or `type`. You can of course select the names if you want to:

```
print(health_data.columns.names)
['subject', 'type']
```

Or indeed, you can also reset them to `None` values, in which case they will disappear, without otherwise affecting the structure of your `df`:

```
health_data.columns.names = [None, None]
health_data.index.names = [None, None]

print(health_data)

         Bob       Guido         Sue      
          HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp
2013 1  31.0  38.7  32.0  36.7  35.0  37.2
     2  44.0  37.7  50.0  35.0  29.0  36.7
2014 1  30.0  37.4  39.0  37.8  61.0  36.9
     2  47.0  37.8  48.0  37.3  51.0  36.5
```

- The other confusing thing is probably that the values from the first level (`0`) are not repeated: they become blanks when they appear as duplicates. Not to worry, they are still there. This is just done to provide a better sense of the relation between the different levels. E.g. your actual index *values* look like this:

```
print(health_data.index)
MultiIndex([(2013, 1),
            (2013, 2),
            (2014, 1),
            (2014, 2)],
           names=['year', 'visit'])
```

- But since `2013` occurs in both `(2013, 1), (2013, 2)`, this is *displayed* as if they are `(2013, 1), ('', 2)`. When you get used to this notation, it is actually much easier to see, e.g. that you just have two years (`2013, 2014`) with two sub levels (i.e. `visit`) for each: `1, 2`.
- Lastly, let's review your [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) example:

```
health_data.iloc[:2, :2]

subject      Bob      
type          HR  Temp
year visit            
2013 1      31.0  38.7
     2      44.0  37.7
```

- We can see now how this works: we are selecting `:2` from the index (so: `0, 1`) and same for the columns. `subject` and `type` are just the names for the columns, `year` and `visit` just the names for the `index`, while `Bob` and `2013` are not repeated in the respective levels `0` of both `MultiIndices` since they are duplicates.
- Suppose we want to select the same data using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), we could do this as follows:

```
health_data.loc[[(2013,1),(2013,2)], [('Bob','HR'),('Bob','Temp')]]

# same result
```

- Or, perhaps more conveniently, we make use of [`index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), and do something like this:

```
health_data.loc[health_data.index.get_level_values(0) == 2013, 
                health_data.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'Bob']

# same result
```

Comment: Oh, finally, I've got it! thank you a lot for the deeply comprehensive explanation!!

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck with your projects. If the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question.